# can long long hold so much symbols?

Tags: c++

well basically can long long int hold number with 100 symbols? for example can long long hold this number -

```
1000000000000000000010000000000000000000100000000000000000001000000000000000000010000000000000000000
```

If no, which type should I use, which could hold so big numbers?

I'm talking about c++.

Comment: What do you need to use this number for?

Comment: Google "C++ BigInteger".

Comment: I will need to sum each digit of that number.

Comment: Then your best bet is probably to have a string with all the digits, and for each char, `sum += digit - '0';`.  For what you want, it's not necessary to treat the "number" as a number in its own right.

Comment: @cHao: C++ does not require any encoding.

Comment: @phresnel: Huh?  What i'm saying is, instead of even bothering with a number, have a string whose value is "100000000001000000..." and work with the individual digits as chars.  The decimal value of each char is the char's ASCII/UTF8 code minus that of '0'.  Makes for a much smaller problem than trying to work with a 100-digit number as a number, since there's no existing type that'll handle that -- and in this case, it's not necessary anyway.

Comment: @cHao: I understand your point, but if you want to write portable code, it is better to use [`<cctype>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctype.h) than to rely on an encoding where '0'..'9' are contiguous.

Comment: @phresnel: every character set in widespread use has '0'..'9' contiguous.  ASCII, Unicode, even EBCDIC.  The only difference is what '0' is.  In fact, AFAIK, the C++ standard *requires* that the range of digits be contiguous.  (See section 2.2)

Comment: @cHao: Astonishing, did not knew this (stackoverflow.com/questions/9416926/c-0-9-required-to-have-contiguous-numeric-values/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For numbers this big you will have to implement a custom type. There is no [standard type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that will be able to hold something this big as a number.

Comment: How I'm able to implement a custom type?

Comment: Make a class that contains all the digits in an array or some other container, and provides all the necessary operators for numbers. Or download and include [one](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/) of the available BigInt classes.

Comment: Could you give me an example of such a class

Comment: See my second sentence in the comment above, the 'one' word is a link to a page with such class.

Comment: Well, basically I need to create it myself, since I'm going to participate in Olympiad, and I won't be able to use class there.

Comment: Then you can check the code and see the logic behind the implementation.

Comment: And would I be able to copy the library content in top of my file, and then just use it as if I would include it?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to use http://gmplib.org/.
As said Alexander, there is no standard type to hold such big string as a number.

Answer (score 1):

No.  `long long` is typically 64 bits, which is enough to hold somewhere around 20 decimal digits.  If you want longer than that, you'll need a library like gmp and whatever struct type it uses.  Or you could roll your own.

Or, if you only care about the individual digits, you don't really need a numeric type at all.  Store the "number" as a `std::string`, work with it by chars, and each digit's value will be equal to its char's ASCII code minus that of `'0'` (which is equal to 48, if you care, but '0' is more self-documenting IMO).

Answer (score 0):

Even if `long long` were to consist of 80 bits (the length of a `double`), it wouldn't hold 10^100 (which is greater than 2^80).

Comment: Where is it specified that a `double` must consist of 80 bits?

Comment: (Actually a `long double` which I believe is the _upper bound_): [HERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double) is the mentioning of an 80-bit `long double`.

Comment: Oh, Wikipedia. Great, that's authoritative. No, Wikipedia is _not_ a specification; and even _that_ states that it's merely a "on x86 most compilers implement".. going on to point out that MSVS (which is incredibly widely used) does not.

Comment: C++ says nothing about the length in bits of `long double`. Different implementations can make it pretty much whatever they want, as your pointing to GCC's personal choice only supports. I never said that I "have never heard about 80 bits".